# Monobehavior issues

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two separate monobehaviors, one, Card, has an enum for 4 suits and a constructor for two values of suit and face value. The second Deck has a for each loop to create instances of my card. It create my 52 cards using a for loop limiting 13 cards per enum but when it tries to make the instances it tell me new is not allowed and that addcomponent is how to do this but I cannot get it to work. I can upload my code for scrutiny shortly.

```
using System;  
using System.Collections;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Linq;  
using UnityEngine;   

public class Deck : MonoBehaviour  
{  
    public int minVal = 1;  
    public int maxVal = 13;  
    List<Card> _cards = new List<Card>();  
    public void Awake()  
    {  
        foreach (var Suit in   Enum.GetValues(typeof(Card.Suit)).Cast<Card.Suit>())  
        {  
            for (int i = minVal; i <= maxVal; i++)  
            {  
                _cards.Add(new Card(Suit, i)); 
            }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

This is the Deck. Below is the Card:

```
using System;  
using System.Collections;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using UnityEngine;  

public class Card : MonoBehaviour  
{  
    public enum Suit { Clubs, Hearts, Diomonds, Spades };  

    public Suit suit;  

    public int faceValue;  

    public  Card(Suit _suit, int _faceValue)  
    {  
        suit = _suit;  
        faceValue = _faceValue;  

    }  
}
```

Comment: "I can upload my code for scrutiny shortly." Always do this - not necessarily the actual code, but a [mcve] - *before* asking the first version of the question. Just describing code is almost never helpful.

Comment: So you have all the info you need, no constructor allowed and you should use addComponent, what problem do you have? Have you had a look at addComponent?

Comment: And please don't put the code into comments - edit your question to put it there, including the precise error message.

Comment: Sorry my code took me a minute to get up there I had realized I was on the wrong pc.

Comment: I was thinking about making subclass NewCard and using the constructor there because the error claims it cannot create a new component with a Monobehavior

Comment: ok i did so now all my Deck references are to Card.Newcard, no errors but it is no longer making my list in unity before I was getting my 52 cards now in the debug there is only my min and max values

Comment: its as if my list is not running

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Unity Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html),

> MonoBehaviour is the base class from which every Unity script derives.

Your script is not meant to be a component, and does not use any of the MonoBehaviour functions. It is just a C# class.

To solve this problem, make the `Card` class not inherit from `MonoBehaviour`. Simply change `public class Card : MonoBehaviour` to `public class Card`.

You can now also delete the `using UnityEngine;` from your Card script.